# 'Echo' html from string in angularjs when the string is on a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ionic tinder cards and each new card should be inserted in an predefined array as an object, likewise:

`{text: "some_text"}`

However, I might be getting html in the string and I want that html to be rendered. **How can I do this considering the object above goes to a predefined array, something happens on the ionic code and then I inject it like this?**

```
<div class="card">
        {{card.text}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ng-bind-html directive: may be require import the sanitize module

```
  <div class="card">
      <span  ng-bind-html="card.text"></span>      
  </div>
```

Comment: And should this work with the default ionic tinder cards code? How should I implement the sanitize in this perspective?

Comment: inject sanitize in your app

Comment: and in this specific perspective? I'm not that familiar with angular

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
<div class="card">
    <span ng-bind-html="card.text"></span>      
</div>
```

If your HTMl contains potentially dangeorus tag (like script tag), you should [sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) it before